# How to define a group of variables in stylus?

Tags: stylus

I was wondering if there was a way to switch between two groups of variable definitions. For example, to change the color theme:

```
$my-blue = #1876d3
$my-white = #f6f6f6
blue-on-white()
  $primary-color = $my-blue
  $secondary-color = $my-white

white-on-blue()
  $primary-color = $my-white
  $secondary-color = $my-blue

// Now I could go back and forth between both schemes to see which one I prefer
blue-on-white()
// white-on-blue()
```

I've tried the above approach using mixins, but it doesn't work with variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is another or better way to do but I found a solution using hashes: http://stylus-lang.com/docs/hashes.html.

**Stylus**

```
blue = #1876d3
white = #f6f6f6

blue-on-white = {
  primary-color : blue,
  secondary-color : white
}

white-on-blue = {
  primary-color : white,
  secondary-color : blue
}

h1
  color blue-on-white[primary-color];
  background-color blue-on-white[secondary-color];

h2
  color white-on-blue[primary-color];
  background-color white-on-blue[secondary-color];
```

**Compiled CSS**

```
h1 {
  color: #1876d3;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}
h2 {
  color: #f6f6f6;
  background-color: #1876d3;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best way. Thanks!